# How to get smtp banner using php

Tags: php, smtp

i need to get the smtp banner using php
i tried like 
`shell_exe("telnet <hostname> 25");`

not giving any result
is there is another way to do that

Comment: Psst, [`fsockopen`](http://php.net/fsockopen)...

Comment: @Charles thats works but the problem is                               " Error: I can break rules, too. Goodbye."

Comment: You'll want to review the SMTP spec.  When you connect, you have to announce your hostname or disconnect after getting the connect banner.

Comment: we need to send lot of request for different servers so we can't do that

Comment: The error message is basically the banner. Probably it is provocative because you are basically rattling doorknobs. How do they (or we) know you are not a spammer?

Comment: ... And how does "we can't do that" follow from the facts you stated?